# Windows authentication or SQL authentication not working after PC upgrading windows 8 to 8.1?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-8.1

I have upgraded my pc Windows 8.0 to Windows 8.1, I am using Microsoft SQL Server R2, and this was working fine with my windows authentication/ SQL authentication when I am using Windows 8.0, but after upgrading my PC windows 8.0 to 8.1 the SQL server was not able to connect using windows authentication or SQL authentication. This problem occurring in only with my credentials, but It is able connect when use other credentials to connect to other database.
[image]

> Please help me some one regarding this problem.!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a work around for this issue.

First create a local account that will work with your sql server. Then switch to your Windows Live account (a seperate user) and modify the shortcut's target.

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:domainName\localAccountName /savecred “pathToExecutable”
```

This should work for any program that needs to use Windows Authentication.